# Why I'm getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax" error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm getting the following error while preparing a mysqli statement.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' phone = ?, status = ?, 'date' between ? AND ? ORDER BY id DESC
>   LIMIT ?' at line 1

mysqli prepared statement:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,role,fullname,phone,email,balance,status,parent, date_format(date,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p') AS date FROM users WHERE id = ?, phone = ?, status = ?, 'date' between ? AND ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?");
if ( false===$stmt ) 
{
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}
$rc = $stmt->bind_param('iiissi',$duid,$dmobile,$dstatus,$sdatetime,$edatetime,$dlimit);
if ( false===$rc ) 
{
  die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$re = $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$re ) 
{
  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
}
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($userid, $urn, $uname, $uphone, $uemail, $ubalance, $ustatus, $up, $udate);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHERE clauses are separated with `AND` (or `OR`) not a comma. You also have another syntax error where you put a column name, `date` in quotes. It should be ticks. Quotes are for strings.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,role,fullname,phone,email,balance,status,parent, date_format(date,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s %p') AS date FROM users 
                         WHERE id = ? AND phone = ? AND status = ? 
                         AND `date` between ? AND ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?");
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to use `AND` or `OR` instead of `,`

Comment: This should probably just be a comment.

Comment: I agree with that, but I've low reputation thus I'm not allowed to comment on questions

Answer (score 1):

This is invalid syntax:

```
WHERE id = ?, phone = ?
```

You want this:

```
WHERE id = ? AND phone = ?
```

Or possibly this:

```
WHERE id = ? OR phone = ?
```

Or some further combination of explicit boolean logic in your `WHERE` clause.

(Repeat for the remaining parts of the `WHERE` clause.)

Answer (score 1):

**Basic Problem**

You tried to combine multiple conditions using comma (,) which is syntactically wrong.

**Quick Solution**

Replace

```
WHERE id = ?, phone = ?
```

with

```
WHERE id = ? AND phone = ?
```

**Bit More Explanation**

You can only have one **WHERE** clause in a single **SELECT** statement. Multiple conditions are combined using logical operators like **AND** and **OR** in a single **WHERE** clause. The comma (,) is applicable in the **IN** clause which can be used in conjunction with the **WHERE** clause.